# Proof of certain Gaussian integral form

Tags: proof-verification, improper-integrals, gaussian-integral

I am having trouble understanding where the following integral form comes from:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a x^2 }e^{-bx}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{\frac{b^2}{a}}$$ I see and understand that the value of the improper Gaussian integral is there, and I surmise that a change of variables is necessary when integrating, but I cannot figure out exactly how to prove this answer.

Comment: This is very similar to the Laplace transform or the moment generating function of a normal random variable. Those calculations will show your integral. You could try completing the square too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a x^2 }e^{-bx} \ dx
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a\left( x+\frac{b}{2a} \right)^2 } e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}} \ dx \\
&=e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a y^2 } \ dy \\
&= e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}
\end{aligned}
$$

So there is a typo in the question, I think.

Comment: Thank you a lot, and yes, that was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is to complete the square in the exponential term.  Observe that

$$
ax^2 + bx \;\; =\;\; ax^2 + bx + \frac{b^2}{4a} - \frac{b^2}{4a} \;\; =\;\; a \left ( x + \frac{b}{2a} \right )^2 - \frac{b^2}{4a}.
$$

We therefore obtain that

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2} e^{-bx} dx \;\; =\;\; e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a \left ( x + \frac{b}{2a} \right )^2} dx \;\; =\;\; e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}
$$

where a change of variables $u = x + \frac{b}{2a}$ doesn't change the value of the integral.  Can you check to see whether there is a $4$ in the denominator of your exponent in the answer you're supposed to obtain?

Comment: I got the same thing as you.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. Thank you very much, I would put an up arrow if my reputation allowed me too (I gave the answer to jdods because he answered first).

Comment: well, technically Mnifldz "answered first"... but I did comment that completing the square was the trick first... lol. Can we split the points? ;)

Comment: It's fine either way.  @jdods Enjoy the points.  IceFelix, glad to help.