# Inverse Fourier transform: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-{(x-x_0)^2\over2\sigma_x}\right)\exp\left(-i\phi\right)\exp(-ix t)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis

To compute the inverse Fourier transform I need to evaluate the following integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-{(\omega-\omega_0)^2\over2\sigma_\omega}\right)\cdot\exp\left(-i\phi\right)\cdot\exp(-i\omega t)\;\mathrm{d}\omega$$

Can I ask you guys for a hint how I should proceed? What are the common methods for tackling such problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may just recall the [gaussian integral result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180168/proof-of-certain-gaussian-integral-form/1180179#1180179) :
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-a{(x-x_0)^2}\right)\mathrm{d}x= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}},\quad \Re a>0,\,x_0 \in \mathbb{C},
$$ and rewrite your initial integral 
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-{(\omega-\omega_0)^2\over2\sigma_\omega}\right)\cdot\exp\left(-i\phi\right)\cdot\exp(-i\omega t)\;\mathrm{d}\omega$$
as
$$I=\exp\left(-i\phi\right)\cdot\exp(\frac{t^2\sigma_\omega}{2}-i\omega_0 t)\cdot\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-{(\omega+it\sigma_\omega-\omega_0)^2\over2\sigma_\omega}\right)\mathrm{d}\omega$$ leading to

> $$
> I=\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_\omega}\cdot\exp\left(-i\phi\right)\cdot\exp(\frac{t^2\sigma_\omega}{2}-i\omega_0 t).
> $$