# How to find this integral from Gaussian integral?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

How to find $$\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2-\frac{b}{x^2}}dx$$ using gaussian integral?

I tried complete the square: $$-ax^2-\frac{b}{x^2}=-\left(\sqrt{a}x+\frac{\sqrt{b}}{x}\right)^2+2\sqrt{ab}$$, but what next?

I tried integration by parts $u=e^{-ax^2-\frac{b}{x^2}}, dv=dx$, but what next?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Please, see update.

Comment: Completing the square was the right thing. But integration by parts won't help. Use the fact $\int _0 ^\infty e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt \pi /2$  or try to prove it. Here you can find similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180168/proof-of-certain-gaussian-integral-form

Comment: I can use the fact you've written. I completed the square, but what to do with $\frac{\sqrt{b}}{x}$?

Comment: Found exact same question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496088/how-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-exp-ax2-frac-bx2-dx-for-a-b0