# Computing the integral $\int e^{2i(a-b)x}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, gaussian-integral

I am pretty stuck when I tried to calculate the Wigner function for the coherent state. Below is part of the equation that I find very challenging.
$$
\int e^{2i(a-b)x}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}\mathrm{d}x\int e^{2i(c-d)y}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}\mathrm{d}y
$$
where $a,b,c,d$ is real numbers and $i$ is complex number index.

Please show me a way to solve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof of certain Gaussian integral form](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180168/proof-of-certain-gaussian-integral-form)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} dx$ with complex analysis](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34767/int-infty-infty-e-x2-dx-with-complex-analysis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $$\int e^{2i(a-b)x}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx = e^{-2(a-b)^2}\int e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x - 2(a-b)i)^2}dx.$$

And you can follow [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34767/int-infty-infty-e-x2-dx-with-complex-analysis).